# How to test a public/private keypair in C++?

Tags: c++, c, openssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

Is there a way to verify that a given private key matches a given public key? I want to check them using C++

Comment: is there any method to get their modulus in C++ ?

Comment: can you give me an example for it using openssl and c++

Comment: The modulus is part of the private key if I'm not mistaken. Libraries handling the key pairs should be able to also provide/extract the modulus from the key. Cryptopp is an example

Comment: I was just answering "is there any method to get their modulus in C++ ?"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the public key algorithm that uses the keys, and how those keys are encoded.  For example, an RSA public key consists of two parameters 'n' and 'e', while a private key consists of those plus 'd', and possibly 'p' and 'q' as well.  All of these params are large integers, generally represented using the internal form of some large integer library.  So to compare a public and private key you just need to check that 'n' and 'e' match.  Depending on the library and system used, you may even be able to ignore 'e', as it might be a constant.

Using OpenSSL that might look something like:

```
RSA *pubkey = PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY(...);
RSA *privkey = PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(...);

if (!BN_cmp(pubkey->n, privkey->n)) {
    // same modulus, so the keys match
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.cryptopp.com/, it has the utilities for checking key pairs.

As a general rule, the private key should be able to decrypt data encrypted using the public key. That's proof that the given key pair is valid.

Comment: And for verification in the other direction, e.g. if you don't have/want access to the private key: anything [signed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29#Signing_messages) with the private key should verify against the public key.